# Eliminar caracteres desde la aparición de un patrón

Tags: r, regex, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente problema: Cuento con un vector que es de la siguiente forma:

```
vector = c("100%35%","10%50%","0.50%1","2.5%")
```

Me gustaría eliminar para cada elemento, todo lo que continua luego de la primera aparición del "%"

Mi salida deseada seria:

```
"100%"  "10%"   "0.50%" "2.5%"
```

Cualquier expresión regular eficiente me ayudaría un montón

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando la expresión `"^(.+?)%"` se extrae todo lo que hay desde el comienzo hasta el primer %.

```
vector = c("100%35%","10%50%","0.50%1","2.5%")

stringr::str_extract(vector, pattern = "^(.+?)%")

[1] "100%"  "10%"   "0.50%" "2.5%"
```

Answer (score 3):

Si no te molesta usar una solución sin patrones regulares, lo que se puede es:

1. Dividir cada cadena por el `%`
2. Extraer en cada caso solo el primer elemento
3. Agregar el porcentaje

Algo así:

```
paste0(sapply(strsplit(vector, '%'), `[[`, 1), '%')

[1] "100%"  "10%"   "0.50%" "2.5%"
```